# How to implement a ViewFactory in Android

Tags: android, model-view-controller, factory-pattern

I have an application that runs on 3 platforms: J2ME, BlackBerry and Android. It has a module with the common code and others with the platform-specific code (for each platform).

We are using a MVC architecture. At first, we left the View and the Controller to be implemented in each platform. But we were getting different behaviors or triplicated code. So we decided to unify the Controller.

Now we have a ViewFactory to be implemented in each platform. In the common code, we just get the views, set it's controller and everything runs nice.

The problem is that I'm not able to do that in Android. I can't instantiate an Activity myself, I have to send an Intent and let the system create it. An Activity looks like a "View plus Controller". I want just the View part. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Tricky situation. You may want to change the view of the current activity with a new view which I think will not be very performance wise good :(. However just a suggestion

Comment: Activity actually is a controller. View part is a layout inflated from xml. setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout) is a part setting view to a controller.